# Can I remove all missing songs without having to do it one at a time?

Tags: itunes, music

When I have iTunes on shuffle, I invariably end up hitting a song iTunes can't find, and then I have to tell it to start shuffle over again (until I hit another song it can't find).

Is there an easy way to go through and remove songs that it can't find from the list of all my songs? Or do I just have to go through manually and remove them as I encounter them?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a work-around I found:

1. Create a playlist in iTunes and call it whatever you want (I called
   mine "existing songs").
2. Go to your "All Songs" view, select your entire library, and drag it into the "existing songs" playlist. iTunes will not add missing songs to this playlist, which means "existing songs" will only include songs without an exclamation point.
3. Create a new smart playlist with the rule "Playlist is not
   existing songs". Name it whatever you want (like "Exclamation").
4. Your new smart playlist will contain only the missing songs, you can re-download them or delete them as you wish.

Source: [LifeHacker](http://lifehacker.com/find-and-sort-the-missing-exclamation-point-tracks-in-1666462567)